# Why does my Eclipse crash all the time?

Tags: eclipse, crash, java, ubuntu-10.10

Somehow stupid question, I have to admit - hope it won't cost me too many points.

To make it clear: I would also be happy if you can help me find the reason for the crashes. I wouldn't expect a precise answer.

However, I don't see why my Eclipse is crashing (freezing) all the time. Mostly when I save a file.

For some reason, crashes seem to increase lately...

I use Eclipse `Helios (Version: 3.6.1)` and Java version `1.6.0_20` (OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.2) (6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu2) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)) on Ubuntu 10.10 (64-Bit).

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly do these crashes manifest? The process freezes? Does it consume CPU cycles when that happens? Or is there actually a JVM segfault?

Comment: I don't exactly know why, but Eclipse doesn't seem to work well at all with the 64bit JVM that comes with Ubuntu. It works well with the sun-java6-jdk package though.

Comment: hm, is there a way to check if my crashes are really Open JDK related?
When Eclipse crashes the window turns dark and Eclipse doesn't response no more. No significant increase of CPU-consumption. When I quit and restart Eclipse, everything works fine again - sometimes it tells me something of a problem with a .log file.

Comment: it crashes for me too all the time. it used to crash with Helios and now with Indigo.
It usually happens when after some idle time, i Clean+Build, and boom.... the IDE closes all of a sudden with exit code as 1... I am using Eclipse Indigo + Windows 7 + JDK 1.6, Tomcat 6.0 ![God Help us!!!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IqkLm.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try installing `sun-java6-jdk` from the `partner`repository.

Comment: hm, I thought on this, but Oracle made it easy not to like them lately... This is why I don't want to do that.

Comment: OpenJDK is still not in par with Sun JDK, sadly... Especially the font rendering differs very much.

Comment: @Steve because OpenJDK is known to crash Eclipse? Read comments before you -1 something.

Comment: I use java version "1.6.0_17"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.7.5) (rhel-1.16.b17.el5-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)                                                                              It works just fine.

Comment: For me, I had do 2 things: Change to Oracle Java; Stop using [oxygen gtk](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1241532)(btw, I use Mageia and not Ubuntu/Kubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

What version of Firefox you are using? The problem may be in xulrunner. Firefox 4 uses xulrunner 2.0, but eclipse 3.6 aren't compatible with it. Read more [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=943398)

Comment: In the meantime I swiched from Ubuntu to Debian and from OpenJDK to Sun JDK. Although I still don't like Oracle too much, at least there JDK works better.

Answer (score 0):

i also have had problems running eclipe with the open jdk,  you can try to install sun's/oracle's jdk and run eclipse with it

Comment: Isn't there a way to check if my problem is really Open jdk - related before I do that?

Comment: maybe taking a look at the error log, but i really can't tell =S

Comment: sounds interresting - maybe if I can google the error, there is a solution. Where do I find it?

Comment: From the menu click "window"->"Show View"->"Others" and it should be listed there as "Error Log"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the sun-jdk instead to run Eclipse and see if that helps?

Comment: hm, I thought on this, but Oracle made it easy not to like them lately... This is why I don't want to do that.

Comment: You can always try the IBM JDK: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/linux/download.html