# Eclipse keep closing suddenly

Tags: eclipse, crash

Recently I have lots of problems with eclipse, it keeps on crashing, closing abruptly, don't work well at all.

It happens too much, like in every 10 -15 minutes.

The CPU and RAM are 50% free when this happens.

This is the `eclipse.ini` file:

```
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
    -showsplash
    org.eclipse.platform
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize

    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -vmargs
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx512m
```

What is the problem ? It's really bothering!

Comment: Please refer [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549405/why-does-my-eclipse-crash-all-the-time)

Comment: this is not a solution ,but this is how i used to avoid such scenarios.
Take a back up of your projects from the work space.Download a new eclipse and use it hence.

Comment: Check <WORKSPACE>/.metadata/.log and post logged messages, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the line

```
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
```

to eclipse.ini

but if you are using this windows 7 then rather add

```
 -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Even try running ecipse as administrator. If this even works then try opening with java.exe instead of javaw.exe. I hope this will work!

Comment: Can you explain about UseCompressedOops parameter and why use it in windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

open eclipse.ini or eclipse configuration file and add below command as first line

-clean

now save and try to open eclipse.
this worked for me.
Have a nice time.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Workspace.
Import your stuffs into it.
That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First before you do ANYTHING check the log: Look at the workspace/.metadata/.log file. In my case it was just some error with a subversion update using subclipse.

Answer (score 0):

On eclipse neon.

On a specific project.

Last thing some days ago was install lombok.

For some days everythig was ok.

From yestarday same problem, eclipse crash after some seconds, after open.

Removed from eclipse.ini this line.
-javaagent:D:\eclipse-neon\lombok.jar

Now eclipse restarted to work

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to a hidden directory in your Eclipse Workspace named .metadata, delete it, and start eclipse. Files in the .metadata directory seem to cause recurrent problems once Eclipse begins to crash.

Comment: This deletes also your settings for imported projects.