# Eclipse indigo randomly shutdowns

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using windows 7 64bit and everytime I code (java core only) in Eclipse Indigo, for some reasons, eclipse randomly shutdowns after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or even when <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd> in debugging process. After eclipse shutdowns, the 'javaw.exe' still remains in Task Manager so I have to turn it off manually in order to renew another coding session in eclipse. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Its bug in Eclipse https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=485094

Comment: Thanks sForSujit but i still cannot find the solution

Comment: it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602413/eclipse-keep-closing-suddenly

Comment: @mustafacil i read it before, tried it but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the lastest version of Eclipse Indigo from Eclipse's Homepage, and i still haven't seen any crash till now. I think it works!

Comment: @shmosel My project uses Indigo in the beginning stage

Comment: So? What's stopping you from updating?

Comment: In the beginning stage of my project, i have to use Indigo, cannot use the newer version. It's mandatory

Comment: Thanks! Whatever, i found the solution